B2 visa inviter passport expired
My parents have a B2 visa interview coming up soon. Most websites mention that I (as inviter) need to include a copy of my passport with their application, but my passport is expired (not my parents of course!). I'm a green card holder.
Will this be an issue?
Thanks for your help!

Where did you see that? Go through the checklist provided by the consulate.

@littleadv you are right! the checklist doesn't call out for inviter/affidavit passport information and it also specifically calls out that affidavit information cannot be used for B2 visa decision making process.

Such a requirement wouldn't make sense. Green card holders are not required to have a passport (though most do), and most US citizens don't have a passport.

Clearly stated in the government site that "Visa applicants must qualify based on their ties abroad/to their home country, rather than assurances from U.S. family and friends. A letter of invitation or Affidavit of Support is not needed to apply for a visitor visa. If you choose to bring a letter of invitation or Affidavit of Support to your interview, please remember it is not one of the factors used in determining whether to issue or deny the visa." That means affidavit visa expiration is also a non-issue.
